# Django Admin: search by date with url parameters

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model defined like this in Django 1.11:

```
class MyModel(Models.Model):
    ... some fields...

    created_date = models.DateTimeField() #YYYY-MM-DD h:m:s
```

Now I want be able to search im MyModel by date in my template. To do that I extended change_list and all was right.

My problem is: what I have to do for retrive object(s) with a specific created_date?

Suppose you want the element(s) created at 2017-12-13.
If I go to the shell I achieve this by:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(created_date__date='2017-12-13')
```

And all work ok, and I get my data. 
But why the __date operator do not work in URL? If I put the __date operator in url, like this:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/admin/.../?created_date__date=2017-12-13
```

I get an error: /?e=1

So I tested another way by using __lte and __gte operators.
Like before you want object created at 2017-12-13, so I combined __lte and __gte operators in this way:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(created_date__gte='2017-12-13', created_date__lte='2017-12-13')
```

But in this case I get an empty query set.
Also in this way:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/admin/.../?created_date__gte=2017-12-13&created_date__lte=2017-12-13
```

So, my questions:

1. Why __lte and __gte operators work as URL parameters and __date no (I get /?e=1)? I have tested with other dates and nothing ghange.
2. How can I get a specific created_date object(s)?

Comment: Hi, Can you give more details please ? The views and the url definition.

Comment: There i no views definitions, I use normal Django admin, like this: http://withice.blogspot.it/2015/07/advanced-search-in-django-admin-between.html

Answer (score 5):

If you want to search function in django admin, you should add `search_fields` in your ModelAdmin.

I don't know well about your model admin (cause you didn't upload it). But if you only register model to admin, try using `ModelAdmin`

```
    from django.contrib import admin

    from Myapp.models import MyModel


    @admin.register(MyModel)
    class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        # you can set so many things in admin. please check django doc
        ...
        # be aware it should be tuple. If you have only one, please add comma 
        search_fields = ('created_at',)
```

Then you can see search input in your admin page. If you search by `2017-12-18` (or just `2017` or `2017-09` is also possible), you can get search get parameter in your url (such as `admin/.../?q=2017-09-29`)

Now you can use that url in admin.

Happy hacking!

Comment: !Oh your created column is `created_date`, so use that instead of created_at